# Mongoose - Select documents with array of objects as search parameter

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have not been able to find something regarding my issue - I might have been searching for the wrong thing though.

I have a fairly simple document structure in MongoDB:

```
const Entry = new mongoose.Schema({
    course: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    },
    year: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    group: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        required: true
    }
});
```

(Shortened it for better readability.)

I need to find all `Entries` that match with one of the `Courses` (schema below):

```
const Course = new mongoose.Schema({
        course: String,
        year: Number,
        group: String,
        title: String
    });
```

I could use a for-loop to execute a find for every element in my `Courses`-Array and then do something like that:

```
Course.find({some condition}).then(courseschema => {
    for (let i = 0; i < courseschema.length; i++) {
        TimetableEntry.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    year: courseschema[i].year,
                    course: courseschema[i].course,
                    title: courseschema[i].title,
                    group: courseschema[i].group
                }
            }
        ]);
    }
});
```

Is there a way to do this in a simple query/db operation/aggregation pipeline? I'd like to avoid to have a bunch of queries executed after one and another.
Help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why don't you have title as a sub property to course?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your desired query output, I'd reorganise the datastructure to something like this (NB, pseudo code-ish):

```
CourseSchema({
  "year": Number,
  "group": String,
  "title": String
});
```

Then you can perform a `aggregate` operation and format the output using [`project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) for example.

Comment: However, how do I 'search' for all matching courses from the entry's schema? I haven't found a way to search for complete objects. "Match all entries that match on of the courses [it's sub-properties year, group and title]."

Comment: I edited my original question which hopefully makes it more clear.